# Convert JObject to System.Object using runtime type

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have a big JSON string I receive from a third-party library (so, I'm unable to change its format). I deserialize it using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. Then, two properties of this newly created object are: JObject and its corresponding System.Type. So, I need to implement the method below to parse it to System.Object of known at runtime System.Type.

```
object ConvertJObjectToObject(Type t, JObject o)
{
    return ........
}
```

JObject.ToObject is a generic method and works only with compile-type types. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject requires JSON string as its first argument, but I have parsed JObject on this stage, and do not want to call ToString() on JObject.

Is there any elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload that takes Type as parameter:

```
return o.ToObject(t);
```

Comment: Not sure why, but my JSON.NET does not have such method.

Comment: Well, okay. I figured out the reason. 4.5 version of JSON.NET does not have this feature, current version 6.0 has. Thx, valid answer.